# adding up the value of an array with another array

Tags: arrays, node.js, sorting, sum

can I get the sum of amount if I have an array like the one below?

```
[{"_id":"5e154cf38c52231ee19f8",
  "refunds":[
    {"_id":"5e38f10a754fcf3d48015",
     "reason":"refund 1",
     "amount":50000,
     ]},
 {"_id":"5e1578b48c52231ee19f8",
  "refunds":[
    {"_id":"5e37e09ef9ea5e3784043",
     "reason":"refund 1",
     "amount":100000,
    {"_id":"5e37e12a02c27c14580a1",
     "reason":"refund 2",
     "amount":100000,
    {"_id":"5e38f02b754fcf3d48015",
     "reason":"refund 3",
     "amount":50000,
     ]},
  {"_id":"5e1578b48c52231ee19f8",
   "refunds":[]
}]
```

I hope to get res = 300000

Comment: wrong json you have inserted here

Comment: This is the result of the query that I changed to JSON :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be relatively straightforward, we create a flat array of all refund objects using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), then we'll use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum the total amount.

I've added another function, sumRefundAmountsII to workaround JavaScript environments that do not support.flatMap (pre ES2019)

```js
const data = [ { "_id": "5e154cf38c52231ee19f8", "refunds": [ { "_id": "5e38f10a754fcf3d48015", "reason": "refund 1", "amount": 50000 } ] }, { "_id": "5e1578b48c52231ee19f8", "refunds": [ { "_id": "5e37e09ef9ea5e3784043", "reason": "refund 1", "amount": 100000 }, { "_id": "5e37e12a02c27c14580a1", "reason": "refund 2", "amount": 100000 }, { "_id": "5e38f02b754fcf3d48015", "reason": "refund 3", "amount": 50000 } ] }, { "_id": "5e1578b48c52231ee19f8", "refunds": [] }];

function sumRefundAmounts(array) {
    // Get an array of all refunds.
    const refunds = array.flatMap(obj => obj.refunds);
    // Sum amount for each refund.
    return refunds.reduce((sum, refund) => { 
        return sum + refund.amount;
    }, 0);
}

console.log("Total amount:", sumRefundAmounts(data));

// Use this function if your JavaScript environment complains about .flatMap
function sumRefundAmountsII(array) {
    // Use a work around if we don't have flatMap... 
    const refunds = [].concat.apply([], array.map(obj => obj.refunds));
    // Sum amount for each refund.
    return refunds.reduce((sum, refund) => { 
        return sum + refund.amount;
    }, 0);
}

console.log("Total amount (no flat map):", sumRefundAmountsII(data));
```

Comment: wow, I just found out about flatMap. new information to me. thank you very much

Comment: Yes, flatMap is extremely useful. It's very new to JavaScript (that may be why you haven't seen if before!). It became part of the language in ES2019 (ES10).

Comment: "array.flatMap is not a function". i think, i follow exacly how u did. but still got error.

Comment: This may be because you're using a slightly older version of JavaScript. I'll provide a solution that does not require flatMap to work around this problem!

Comment: run perfectly, I intend to use .map and .flat separately. but this is better to understand

Answer (score 0):

Before answering ... I assume 2 things -

1st - you are looking answer in the Java.  2nd - And you can do things much easier way in java List :

Let we make 2 classes Refund & Composite (Containing List)-

Refund Class -

```
package com.sabre.ticketing.dhs.service.create.domain;

public class Refund {

    String _id;
    String reason;
    int    amount;

    public Refund(String _id, String reason, int amount) {
        this._id = _id;
        this.reason = reason;
        this.amount = amount;
    }


    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

}
```

And here is Composite Class as -

```
package com.sabre.ticketing.dhs.service.create.domain;

import java.util.List;

public class Composite {

    String _id;
    List<Refund> refunds;

    public Composite(String _id, List<Refund> refunds) {
        this._id = _id;
        this.refunds = refunds;
    }

    public List<Refund> getRefunds() {
        return refunds;
    }
}
```

The calculation technique is in SumCalc class -

```
package com.sabre.ticketing.dhs.service.create.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SumCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Composite> composites = List.of(new Composite("5e154cf38c52231ee19f8", List.of(new Refund("5e38f10a754fcf3d48015", "refund 1", 50000))),
                new Composite("5e154cf38c52231ee19f8",
                        List.of(new Refund("5e37e09ef9ea5e3784043", "refund 1", 100000),
                                new Refund("5e37e12a02c27c14580a1", "refund 2", 100000),
                                new Refund("5e38f02b754fcf3d48015", "refund 3", 50000))),
                new Composite("5e154cf38c52231ee19f8", new ArrayList<>()));
        // Basically get you Json converted into composites list.. for simplicity and dont want to jackson thing i have initialized list  as new ..

        Integer finalSum = composites.stream()
                .map(Composite::getRefunds)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(Refund::getAmount)
                .reduce((sum, val) -> sum + val)
                .orElse(0);

        System.out.println("final Sum is " + finalSum);

        }

}
```

Run the SumClac ...

---

final Sum is 300000

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: is it same in node js (javascript) ?

Comment: Per my very limited knowledge in JavaScript - I have not seen array List there, but pls check. Honestly I answered in Java presuming you might be looking in Java also..

Comment: woke, I'll make a reference from it